# Mysql - Increment variable during import

Tags: mysql

I'm importing various perfmon style CSV logs and would like to add a SET command to update a field with a line number variable as it imports, something like:

```
SET @varcount = 0;LOAD DATA INFILE '/file' INTO TABLE mytable ....... (field1, field2, field3) SET linenumberfield = @varcount:=@varcount+1;
```

However mysql errors out with a syntax problem near the "linenumberfield = ...." bit. I've tried a variety of var names in case I was stepping on any reserved words and have tried various combinations of with/without the colon. All the previous posts I've seen on here have been regarding SELECT or UPDATE commands so I'm wondering if the problem is that I'm trying to do it in an import?

Appreciate any help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tested successfully:

```
set @varcount = 0;
LOAD DATA INFILE '/file.txt' INTO TABLE attachments SET `name` = @varcount;
```

But the [MySQL Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) says:

> Assignments in the SET clause should have only column names on the
>   left hand side of assignment operators.

You can, alternatively, add a trigger on BEFORE or AFTER INSERT to do counting.

Comment: Thanks, although linenumberfield is the name of the col I want to update with the variable  and not a var itself...unless I'm missing something with the way that the SET should work?

Comment: Thanks, I'd kind of guessed this was the case but was hoping I was wrong. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This has worked! It's weird that I'm setting other columns without the ticks but this one needs them. Don't care, it works!!